# Icenium Graphite Show / Hide Footer tab

Tags: javascript, html, graphite, icenium

i have Mobile application in Icenium Graphite.

i have footer with tabs.

but i don't want to show all the tabs at once to user.

on login i want to show some tabs and so on.

i have tried using

```
                $("#addVehicle").show();
                $("#addVehicle").removeAttr("style");
                $("#addVehicle").attr("style", "display:block");
```

and style="display:none" at addVehicle
but it is not working.

Also i tried data-role="view" and data-bind="invisible: isLoggedIn" but it is not for hiding or showing just a single tab.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `data-show` event of the view you are navigating to after login, you should be able to hide/show tabs by id. Have you tried that? If not, please provide a jsfiddle example.

Comment: @ Rob Lauer I tried following things: 1. Show Hide Anchor Tags using Show/Hide Methods 2. using css 3. using data-bind (it is useful only for <div>)

Comment: I would need to see more of your code to help you here. Can you create a jsfiddle or at least paste the relevant parts here?